# Как инициализировать событие отправки формы для <button type="button">?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма:

```
 <form id="spageForm" method="post" action="index.php">
     <button type="submit" name="save"></button>
     <button type="button" name="delete"></button>
 </form>
```

Мне нужно с помощью JS (желательно jQuery) инициализировать событие `submit()` для `<button type="button" name="delete"></button>`.

На данный момент нашел способ обычной отправки формы: `$('#spageForm').submit();`, но в `index.php` не отправляется `$_POST['delete']`, а нужно, чтобы отправлялась.

Comment: <button type="button | reset | submit">...</button> из htmlbook

Comment: я выбрал button, а не submit, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку не отправлялась форма, а выполнялся мой код, после выполнения которого должно отработать событие: будто бы я тыкнул по кнопке из type=submit

Comment: Да, только без клика

Comment: Нет, только delete. save я оставил в примере, чтобы показать, что у меня две кнопки. Если бы она была, то проблема решилась бы указанием type='submit'  для delete   и onsubmit="return false; для формы. А вот с двумя кнопками так не выйдет

Comment: Грубо говоря да, так и есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить в форму скрытое поле:

```
<form id="spageForm" method="post" action="index.php">
     <input type="hidden" name="" id="form_action">
     <button type="submit" name="save"></button>
     <button type="button" name="delete"></button>
</form>
```

И тогда скрипт будет:

```
document.getElementById("form_action").name = "delete";
document.getElementById("form_action").value = "y";
$('#spageForm').submit();
```

Или просто делать

```
var data = $('#spageForm').serialize();
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "index.php",
  data: data+"&delete=y"
})
```

Comment: За идею скрытого поля спасибо, только я писал, что $('#spageForm').submit(); не подходит

Comment: Ну я же написал в скрипте добавление скрытого поля и делаю отправку формы, по такой схеме Вам придёт `$_POST['delete'] == "Y"`

Comment: хочешь сказать, что $_POST['save'] не придет?

Comment: @EvgeniiZaets нет, save не придёт так как форма отправлена без нажатия на кнопку save. Она просто отправляет текущие параметры формы

Comment: Сори уже тупить начал, по идее должно работать

Comment: Всё работает. Проверял же

Answer (score -2):

Решил проблему. Добавил скрытое поле `<button type="submit" name="del"></button>` и отправил форму с помощью `$("button[name='del']").click();`